# Gradle tasks hangs after starting HttpFileServer

Tags: docker, gradle

I am trying to build a Docker image where in the Dockerfile I would like to pull the files using a file server instead of using the ADD directive(to not create a layer). So in my Gradle script itself, I ran the server like this:

```
SimpleHttpFileServerFactory factory = new SimpleHttpFileServerFactory()
server = factory.start(new File(location), port)
```

I am using the 'se.transmode.gradle' Gradle plugin to build the image. The problem I am facing is that after running the file server, the buildDocker task hangs and the --debug arg just shows regular check message like below the whole time:

```
19:28:59.110 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
19:28:59.110 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
19:28:59.110 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

If I read the file I want to copy in the container directly then everything works fine.

If I use the generated Dockerfile, which pulls the file from the file server ... with the 'docker build' command while running file server in gradle on the side ... then also everything works fine.

My buildDocker task looks like:

```
task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: [buildRpm, generateDockerfile, startHttpFileServer]) {
push = false
applicationName = 'test-app'
tagVersion = "$rootProject.appVersion"
dockerfile = file("${buildDir}/docker/tmp/Dockerfile")

doFirst {
    copy {
        from("${buildDir}/distributions/${applicationName}-${tagVersion}.noarch.rpm")
        into("${stageDir}/target")
    }
    copy {
        from("${rootDir}/Packaging/src/docker/entrypoint.sh")
        into("${stageDir}/target")
    }
    exec {
        commandLine "docker", "login", "-u", "${username}", "-p", "${password}", "${registryUrl}"
    }
}

doLast {
   exec {
        commandLine "docker", "logout", "${registryUrl}"
   }
}
  }
  buildDocker.finalizedBy stopHttpFileServer
```

Comment: And why do you expect this to work? You are starting a server on main thread and that will keep listening to incoming request and not terminate. So nothing further will be run. You need to somehow run that as a background task and not block execution

Comment: As a test I created a test task, started the server in the doFirst block ... stopping it in the doLast ... With some print statements between ... Worked fine.

Comment: Can you request a resource from the server in between too, instead of just printing log

Comment: yes, ...task tryServer(){
    def HttpFileServer server = null;
    try{
        SimpleHttpFileServerFactory factory = new SimpleHttpFileServerFactory()
        server = factory.start(new File("${buildDir}/docker/target"), (int)8001)
        exec{
          commandLine "wget", "http://${hostnamefs}:8001/test.sh"
        }
        println("doing some stuff")
    }finally{
        if (server != null){server.stop();}}}
... this works fine.

Comment: Okie post your Dockerfile also to the question

Comment: I am suspecting the problem is related to the docker plugin somehow. Let me try a different plugin to verify this.

Comment: Ok, so changing the plugin solved this problem but with the current Gradle task code, the server keeps running even if the task fails.